# ES6 JS - Unable to access static function in associated class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand why I am unable to call a static function **on** Class A **from** Class B. Example code:

```
class Aye {
  static functionOne () {
    console.log('Im static!')
  }
}

class Bee {
  constructor () {
    Aye.functionOne()
  }
}
```

From what I've read about statics, this *should* work, however it does not.

Comment: What have you read about statics? How do you know it's correct with respect to JS?

Comment: I'm stuck here, I've run your code in the console (in chrome) and it runs fine. What are you running this code on/with? [Seems like IE doesn't like it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Remember to create an instance of `Bee` -> `const bee = new Bee()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I was trying to do the above code using Node & Modules; in a browser the code actually works fine. With Node, I had to *include* class Aye *within* the constructor, otherwise the reference is undefined. The code ends up looking like this:

```
class Bee {
  constructor () {
    const Aye = require('./aye.js')
    Aye.functionOne()
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Sounds like a circular dependency issue?